# Select were Col1 contains range of other column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to ask for help with my query. 
Sheet1 contains another sheet that is imported with the formula import range. The first column contains the first names, the second row is the date, and the rest of the sheet contains additional data. Sheet2 lists the parts of the names that are on Sheet1. 
I would like Sheet3 to show all the dates and data for the names from Sheet1 that are on Sheet2. However, with the query, an error pops up:
"Formula parse error."

`=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:IM, "select * where Col1 contains "='Sheet2'!A1:A15"")`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` with `match()`, like this:

`=filter( 'Sheet1'!A1:IM, match('Sheet1'!A1:A, 'Sheet2'!A1:A15, 0) )`